# Remove space in a date string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a date from a database that sometimes has spaces in the times (there isn't a way to clean up DB as I don't have control). I need to remove the spaces so I can format it to a Javascrpt date.

For example:

```
5 : 03 PM
```

As you can see, this is incorrect. I've looked at Moment.js and Regex to remove spaces around the colon, but not sure how that's done or if that's the proper way. Is there a way to remove this space?

Thanks all!

Comment: I'd go with a regular expression replacement. What did you try? Is that the full string from the DB or just a part of it?

Comment: There's different ways to do it, even with core javascript.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I doubt OP wants to remove **all** the spaces

Comment: I only looked if it was possible. I'm not good with Regex so was looking for some kind of similar code now that I could use. Tried var badttime = '4 : 57 PM' 

var res = timee.replace(' : ', ':');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only to delete the space around the colon, try the following; (where `$1` refers to the first capture group, that is the only one `(:)`)

`a.replace(/\s*(:)\s*/, "$1");`

or if you wish to simplify it further, without any capturing group;

`a.replace(/\s*:\s*/, ":");`

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I was close, but had the second value backwards. Appreciate the help @bureaquete

Comment: Why bother with the brackets and $1 when you can just replace with ":"?

Comment: Why save a reference ti the colon? It never changes. Just hard code it. No need to perform extra interpolation. `replace(/\s*:\s*/, ‘:’)`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to, you *can* actually parse that date string with Moment.js, you just need to include the spaces in your formatting string:

```
var time = moment('5 : 03 PM', 'h : m A');
```

Then you can format it however you want:

```
time.format('h:mmA'); // "5:30PM"
time.format('hh:mm A'); // "05:03 PM"
time.format('HH:mm'); // "17:03"
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness you could aviod regexp:

```
'5  :  03pm'.split(':')
  .map(function(part) { return part.trim(); })
  .join(':');
```